# Clarification on the Application of a p-Channel MOSFET in a Circuit Diagram

Tags: mosfet, pcb-design, pmos, reverse-polarity

I am seeking clarification on the application of a p-channel MOSFET as illustrated in the diagram below. Could someone please provide an explanation?

[image: schematic]

In the diagram, legs 1, 2, 6, and 5 serve as drains, while leg 3 functions as the gate and leg 4 as the source. A 12V input is directed into the voltage regulator.

Before delving into my queries, I'd like to establish what I understand to be correct, and I welcome corrections if any inaccuracies are present:

The standard current flow in a p-channel MOSFET is from source to drain when a negative voltage is applied to the gate (Vgs). However, in this scenario, we aim for the current to flow from drain to source, as the positive terminal of the battery is connected to the drain.

The gate is connected to ground, indicating a zero voltage applied to the gate.

Now, onto my questions:

Given our objective to reverse the current flow (from drain to source instead of source to drain), should we apply a positive voltage to the gate rather than a negative one?

Whether the answer to the previous question is affirmative or negative, the following question persists: Since the gate voltage is already zero and the drain possesses 12V with no current flowing, how will the MOSFET be activated?

I appreciate any insights or clarifications on these matters. Thank you.

Comment: \$V_{GS}\$ is ***not*** gate potential. \$V_{GS}=V_G - V_S\$, the ***potential difference*** between gate and source. Since sources are permanently connected to +12V, and gates are at 0V, \$V_{GS}=(0V)-(+12V)=-12V\$, and the MOSFETs are permanently on.

Comment: +12V is connected to Drain not Source.

Comment: Your schematic clearly shows 12V connected to sources.

Comment: here is the datasheet. It shows those legs are drains and not source.

https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMP3056LDM.pdf

Comment: Pins 1, 2, 5, 6 are the drain,pin 4 is the source, and it is pin 4 connected to 12V.

Comment: Oh wait a min ! you are right. Sorry for my foolishness. I am a programmer and i am seeing everything is as 12v is moving from batt to drain and to the source. It is my mistake. Thank you so much.

Comment: can you also explain how this is used for reverse polarity protection? Is it because if the source voltage reduces then mosfet closes ?

Comment: What do you mean by \$V_{IN}\$ on your schematic? The name implies some input, but that doesn't make much sense here.

Comment: An electronic designer draw that. I thing it comest from batt(+)

Comment: In the context of reverse polarity protection, I would argue that the node labelled "12V" is the input (from the battery), and the node labelled "Vin" is actually the *output*, going to some load.

Comment: So is it connected wrong ?

Comment: I've written an answer, which should illustrate my thoughts on this.

Comment: @SimonFitch  I'd expect that Vin was eg a power pack / psu. So he has two protction ccys - one for each energy source.

Comment: @user23910965  The key requirement to understand Simon's answer is that MOSGETs are 2 quadrant devices. As long as Gate is more negative enough relative to Source for a P channel device or more positive for an N channel device THEN the FET will conduct with EITHER polarity applied from drain to source. So, as Simon says, the FET is connected with d-s "backwards to usual but Vgs still needs to be negative to turn the FET on.

Comment: @user23910965  **IMPORTANT** I'm a moderator. (1) It appears that you have used AI to improve your question.  As long as it's your question and you are using the AI as a tool to improve the format then this is (probably) OK. BUT the 1st paragraph (Certainly ..." ) did not read like human input, was wholly unnecessary, and detracted from your question. If using tools to assist you you should read the result carefully and ensure that it is "speaking in your voice". (2) To meet site rules, please add the source of the diagram to your question. eg "Circuit created by me" or "from http:// ... " etc

Answer (score 2):

If this is a reverse polarity protection system, then the node labelled "12V" is misleading. I'll redraw the design with some label changes to reflect the input and output roles less ambiguously:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWVRLu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For negative inputs, \$V_{IN} < 0\$, the body diodes are reverse biased, and the load keeps \$V_{OUT}\$ at 0V. In this condition, source potential \$V_S=0V\$:

$$ V_{GS} = V_G - V_S = (0V) - (0V) = 0V $$

So, for \$V_{IN} < 0\$, the MOSFETs are off, and their body diodes do not conduct. Current \$I=0A\$.

When \$V_{IN}\$ rises above 0V (becoming positive), the body diodes are forward biased, ensuring that source potential \$V_S\$ is never lower than \$V_S = V_{IN} - 0.7\$. Since source potential also rises, \$V_{GS}\$ is:

$$ V_{GS} = V_G - V_S = (0V) - (V_{IN} - 0.7) = -(V_{IN} - 0.7) $$

This will be strongly negative, if \$V_{IN} >> 0\$, the condition required for the MOSFETs to be on, and they conduct strongly. Their impedance drops enough to bypass the body diodes altogether, raising \$V_S\$ to become \$V_S = V_{OUT} = V_{IN}\$.

Comment: Where did you get the 0.7 ?

Comment: @user23910965 It's the forward voltage of a silicon diode, 0.7V